# How is convex hull method used in outlier detection?

Tags: anomaly-detection, outlier, anomaly

[image: Here is some information about convex hull from slides I found in the internet]

I think the slides are bit unclear on what they want to say. Can someone elaborate this with example.

Comment: What is unclear about them?

Comment: I don't understand how convex hull is made and how does it detects outliers..

Comment: You can check the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

Although, looking at the slides, it doesn't make sense to mark the ones with **higher** depth as outliers.